# Removing a windows user using C# (Remotely)

Tags: c#, windows

I have been researching for a solution for some time now:

I have tried `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` and `System.DirectoryServices`.

Currently, I have gotten closes with `System.Directory` services. Here is my code:

```
// Connect to pc    
DirectoryEntry locaDirectoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + machineId);
// Find user by userName
    DirectoryEntry user = locaDirectoryEntry.Children.Find(userName);
// Remove the user
    locaDirectoryEntry.Children.Remove(user);
// Commit the changes
    locaDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges();
```

This code deletes the user, so I cannot see it within **"Local Users and Groups -> Users"** but the user profile however stays and turns into **"Account Unknown"**.

Now, I have been on numerous websites including this but have not been able to find something that does the trick "completely". I need the user profile to be deleted.

Any help/ thoughts is appreciated.

Comment: Deleting a user profile is often a separate step. You might be looking for [`DeleteProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/userenv/nf-userenv-deleteprofilew). Make sure you get their SID before you delete them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I specified above deletes a login from the computer but does not take care of the user profiles as stated by `Damien_The_Unbeliever`.

I have been digging in my PowerShell equivalent to the app that I am making and found how I did it there. I use WMI to delete the user profile.

Here is my working code for any soul who could use it:

```
public string RemoveUser(string machineId, string userName)
{
    string result = null;

    try
    {
        // Create scope and set to computer root.
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + machineId + @"\root\cimv2");

        // Connect.
        scope.Connect();

        // Create the query for user profiles and a searcher.
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserProfile");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

        // Go through each WMI Instance
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
        {
            // Normalize username
            string normalUser = mo["LocalPath"].ToString().Split('\\').Last(); 

            // Check whether this is the user to be deleted
            if (normalUser == userName)
            {
                mo.Delete();
                result = "Found user: " + userName + ". Deleting...";
            }

        }

        // This code deletes a user login
        //DirectoryEntry locaDirectoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + machineId);
        //DirectoryEntry user = locaDirectoryEntry.Children.Find(userName);
        //locaDirectoryEntry.Children.Remove(user);
        //locaDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }

    return result;
}
```

See the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee886409(v=vs.85).aspx) for properties on `UserProfiles`. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobject.delete?view=netframework-4.7.2) is the Delete method.